# How to get token info from Sharekit for Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, sharekit

My app displays a short list of tweets based on a given TV hashtag with the additional ability to post a tweet.

But now twitter has gone oauth for all requests, my tweet list doesnt appear as it was using the old search.atom API.

Therefore, how do I access the search api and pass in OAuth credentials using Sharekit so user authenticates just the once for viewing tweets and posting between sessions.

I have tried using SHKRequest, hoping, that as ShareKit has already authorised it will pass this information through; with no joy, is there some other way of doing this or am I just using it badly/wrong.

```
request = [[[SHKRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=twitter&result_type=recent"]
                          delegate:self
                isFinishedSelector:@selector(sendFinishedSearch:)
                            params:nil
                            method:@"GET"
                         autostart:YES] autorelease];
```

I do need to maintain compatibility with 4.3 API so I cant just use iOS5 Twitter API.

Disclaimer: I am inheriting project from someone so my XCode/ObjC knowledge is being learnt whilst I modify project (I come from C/C++ background), so please ignore my ignorance.

Comment: try this [here](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter)

Comment: Thanks for that, I will look into it ... but as I already have ShareKit for Facebook posting I would prefer to keep with the one framework if at all possible. If there is no other way then I will give STTwitter a go

Answer (score 1):

ShareKit contains an `SHKTwitter` class. It is a subclass of `SHKOAuthSharer`. As such, you can ask it to perform authorisations / refreshes and get the resulting token.

Create an instance of `SHKTwitter` and register as it's delegate. Implement the `- (void)sharerAuthDidFinish:(SHKSharer *)sharer success:(BOOL)success` delegate method. Then call `tokenRequest`. When the delegate method is called, if `success` is `YES` you can get the `accessToken`.

---

```
    SHKTwitter *twitter = [[SHKTwitter alloc] init];
    twitter.shareDelegate = self;
    [twitter tokenRequest];


- (void)sharerAuthDidFinish:(SHKSharer *)sharer success:(BOOL)success
{
    SHKTwitter *twitter = (SHKTwitter *)sharer;

    if (twitter.accessToken != nil) {
        NSLog(@"session: %@, %@", twitterSharer.accessToken.key, twitterSharer.accessToken.secret);
    } else {
        [twitter tokenAccess];
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant get it to actually ask for authorisation so accessToken is empty. I have tried following but it doesnt display any login form:  SHKTwitter *twitter = [[SHKTwitter alloc] init]; twitter.shareDelegate = self; [twitter authorize];

Comment: I wrote the wrong method name yesterday, to start the auth process you should call the `tokenRequest` method.

Comment: Its returning an error about invalid request; looking at the console it could be because OAMutableURLRequest oauth_consumer_key parameter is null; so I set consumer key and secret on the twitter instance and it still fails.

Comment: In your config you should have an app id  (consumer key), secret and callback. Have you got ShareKit setup so you can share via Twitter?

Comment: Yes, I have a default SHKConfiguration file with all the values setup ... posting to twitter is working fine (asked me for authorisation) then posted my tweet after which i called this tokenRequest which still has a null consumer_key value

Comment: What is the 'consumer_key' you refer to? Are you getting an error in the log, or it's the value you're trying to get the token from?

Comment: its in the request url ... <0x9a13930 OAMutableURLRequest.m:(245)> OAMutableURLRequest parameters oauth_consumer_key=(null)&oauth_nonce=5705A324-55BC-42A4-ADC5-D55A90F8E179&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1373028357&oauth_version=1.0; <0x8fae770 OAAsynchronousDataFetcher.m:(51)> starting request:https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token; <0x9a85350 SHKOAuthSharer.m:(109)> tokenRequestTicket Response Body: Failed to validate oauth signature and token; <0x8fae770 OAAsynchronousDataFetcher.m:(137)> connection finished with response:Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32953/discussion-between-dan-and-wain)

Comment: Still can't get this working it seems completely broken, however I will award the bounty as you have spent a lot of time trying t get this resolved for me. Thx

Answer (score -1):

IN SHKOAuthSharer.m class You will get access Token in method:

```
- (void)tokenAccessTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data 
{
    if (SHKDebugShowLogs) // check so we don't have to alloc the string with the data if we aren't logging
        SHKLog(@"tokenAccessTicket Response Body: %@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);

    ///[[SHKActivityIndicator currentIndicator] hide];

    if (ticket.didSucceed) 
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //piyush Added
        NSArray *strArray = [responseBody componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];        
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[strArray objectAtIndex:([strArray count]-1)] forKey:@"TwitterUsername"];


        **self.accessToken** = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
        [responseBody release];

        [self storeAccessToken];

        //[self tryPendingAction];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TwitterDidLogin" object:nil];
    }


    else
        // TODO - better error handling here
        [self tokenAccessTicket:ticket didFailWithError:[SHK error:SHKLocalizedString(@"There was a problem requesting access from %@", [self sharerTitle])]];

}
```